# Angularjs as nodejs framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jsdom

I've been using `angularjs` for a long time and i've got my mind wrapped so much into ng app architecture philosophy, scope, event, service oriented patterns, di and everything.
i thought that using this framework for developing in `nodejs` would be great,
so i tried to develop a very simple `module` with some `directives`, and `services`.. driven by an `.html` file bootstrapped in a [`jsdom`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) context, involving some `ng-repeat` on [files] in a folder, using `require('fs')` inside an angularjs controller..
Well it just worked great!!
So it is possible to develop a nodejs app on top of angularjs, modelling the app in html!
just 1 thing to fix:
`jsdom` is a *real* and complete `dom` with events, bells and whistles running in nodejs..
this causes my test application to run very slow.
so my question is:
is there some light, almost dumb/fake `dom` library for nodejs out there, that supports just the bare necessary features needed by angularjs to work (user interaction features are useless..)?
*[edit]*
looking at comments i guess i didn't explain well the aim of my test:
i'm not trying to make a server-side angular-html builder or template engine.
the test i made demostrate how to develop a general nodejs app that can be modelled with an html that acts as a reactive server-component activator..
the application usecase/purpose could be whatever, from being an httpserver to a standalone application or system-service and shouldn't necessary output an html or an browser-angularjs-app as *output*

-edit-
[here](https://github.com/aleclofabbro/ng-system) is a starting-up project, with the basics and a test ...

Comment: Very interesting idea. I don't have a solution, but this has potential. If it could become less attached to a DOM in general and function more like a standard angular template html then I think you'd really have something.

Comment: I can't at all figure out what you're really trying to do.. Angular should not be used server side. Nodejs supports modules already, so Angular isn't offering anything there, and Angular's module system is notably poor anyway. If you're going to use Angular, that should be on the front end only, and you can create the data service (server api) with node. You'd probably want to use `express` and the various associated node modules that make development easy.

Comment: @m59: why not? `express` would likely be a module `require`d in some module/service inside that app! i love the *declarative* approach of building angular apps.. and i think that it would be very flexible on a server too!

Comment: @colepanike i can't understand what you mean in your *if* statement, i'm glad you like the idea, anyway!

Comment: Think about something like jade-lang. It doesn't rely on some funky DOM manipulations, instead it parses the markup and compiles it. Angular could theoretically do the same thing, thereby acting as a server-side templating language. You'd switch out ajax calls to fill views with filesystem injection. That would require nested parsing too. Essentially to do this right you'd have to re-write some of angulars base code. It would be lot's of work and I'm not sure it would be worth it for the benefit, but still neat.

Answer (score 0):

> is there some light, almost dumb/fake dom library for nodejs out there, that supports just the bare necessary features needed by angularjs to work (user interaction features are useless..) ?

Take a look at [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Comment: had a look to cheerio, seems it's a great tool for manipulating html in jQuery style, but it doesn't do the job.. angular needs a browser environment starting from `window` as global, though that environment could be *dumb* to a large extent

Comment: "The browser" is a system of many subsystems and APIs. Node modules don't do huge insane things like trying to emulate every browser API. Cheerio is for the DOM, which is what you asked about. There are dozens of other APIs encompassed by the `window` object in a browser.